# How to remove space autofill in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have a TextInput and when I autofill my email address I have a space after my email.

[image]
 I try this

```
 const email = values.email.trim();
```

and also

```
 const email = values.email.replace(/\s+/g, ' ');
```

but it's doesn't work. Someone know how to remove the space after the autofill?

```
    return (
      <Formik
        enableReinitialize={true}
        initialValues={{ email: this.props.navigation.getParam("email") }}
        validationSchema={yup.object().shape({
          email: yup
            .string()
        })}
        onSubmit={async (values) => {
          const email = values.email;
        }
      }
      >
        {({ handleChange, handleSubmit, values, errors, touched, setFieldTouched }) => (
          <View>
          {
            <View>
              <TextInput
                value={values.email}
                placeholder="Email"
                autoCapitalize="none"
                autoCorrect={false}
                onBlur={() => setFieldTouched("email")}
                onChangeText={handleChange("email")}
                autoCompleteType={"email"}
              />
              <View>
                <TouchableOpacity
                  onPress={handleSubmit}
                >
                  <Text style={styles.textButton}>Valider</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
              </View>
            </View>
        )}
      </Formik>
    );
```

Comment: can you please show your values object.

Comment: I update my question

Comment: I'm still not able to see `values` object and i believe there's something wrong with it. Please have a look at the [doc example](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput.html) of `TextInput`. It works fine with autofil. If still facing the issue please show more code

Answer (score 4):

If you haven't found a solution for this situation yet, here's one way that solves it:

```
onChangeText={(val) => setFieldValue('login', val.trim())}
```

Instead of using `handleChanges`, you can use `setFieldValue`, then "trim" `val`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<Text
...
value={this.state.emailID}
/>
```

Reuse your trim logic and assign the new value to the state variable(emailID) in "onChangeText" of the textinput